# How to select rows based on dynamic column value?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pandas-loc

First of all, I have following a following dataframe df_A

| sector | SALES | EBIT | DPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| ENERGY | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| FINANCE | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |

and another dataframe df_B

| NAME | sector | SALES | EBIT | DPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| BP | ENERGY | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| TGT | CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| MSFT | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| HSBC | FINANCE | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| GOOG | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| WMT | CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| META | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| CVX | ENERGY | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| JPM | FINANCE | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| MCD | CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |

and so on

this is just an example, and I have a way bigger dataframe than this

what I want to do is to create new dataframes by distinguishing df_B by it's sectors;

where the newly created dataframes follow the order of df_A["sectors"]

and in the end merge them altogether, hopefully in horizontal format

so in the end I want my output to look like

| NAME | sector | SALES | EBIT | DPS | NAME | sector | SALES | EBIT | DPS | NAME | sector | SALES | EBIT | DPS | NAME | sector | SALES | EBIT | DPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | BP | ENERGY | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | HSBC | FINANCE | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | WMT | CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| MSFT | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | CVX | ENERGY | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | JPM | FINANCE | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | TGT | CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| GOOG | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | MCD | CONSUMER | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |
| META | IT | xxxx | yyyy | zzz |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

if the horizontal format above doesn't work, vertical table will also be okay

I'm noob in python and I tried using for loops, dictionary, loc/iloc but somehow none of my codes is working properly...

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101 Will this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create N dataframes, one for each sector, then concatenate them into a single one:

```
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df_B[df_B['sector'] == sector].to_dict('records'))
                    for sector in df_A['sector'].unique().tolist()], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   NAME sector SALES  EBIT  DPS NAME  sector SALES  EBIT  DPS  NAME   sector SALES  EBIT  DPS NAME    sector SALES  EBIT  DPS
0  AAPL     IT  xxxx  yyyy  zzz   BP  ENERGY  xxxx  yyyy  zzz  HSBC  FINANCE  xxxx  yyyy  zzz  TGT  CONSUMER  xxxx  yyyy  zzz
1  MSFT     IT  xxxx  yyyy  zzz  CVX  ENERGY  xxxx  yyyy  zzz   JPM  FINANCE  xxxx  yyyy  zzz  WMT  CONSUMER  xxxx  yyyy  zzz
2  GOOG     IT  xxxx  yyyy  zzz  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  MCD  CONSUMER  xxxx  yyyy  zzz
3  META     IT  xxxx  yyyy  zzz  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Finally!! I got  it! Thanks so much!